# Insertion Sort in case of repeated values, doubly linked list ADT

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am having a weird problem with my insertion sort in the case of repeated values at the tail of the input. The most basic case I have got it to have problems with is the array {A,A,A}. Since I am tracking the initial indices, I am able to tell that this is improperly sorted such that the incorrect indices are stored, such that values are lost. Here is the implementation of the insertion sort:

```
    List A = new List();
    String[] inputArray = {"A","A","A","A"};
    String key;
    int i, j;
    //begin insertion sort
    for (j = 1; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
        i = j - 1;
        key = inputArray[j];
        while (i >= 0) {
            if (key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) > 0) {
                break;
            }
            inputArray[i+1] = inputArray[i];
            A.moveTo(i+1);
            //make sure we aren't trying to insert before first node
            if (i > 0) { A.insertBefore(i); }
            else { A.prepend(i); }
            //remove node at cursor
            A.delete();
            i--;
            System.out.println("inner:  "+ A);
        }
        inputArray[i+1] = key;
        A.moveTo(i+1);
        if (i >= 0) { A.insertBefore(j); System.out.println("insert: " + A);}
        else { A.prepend(j); System.out.println("prepend: " + A);}
        System.out.println("current cursor:" + A.getIndex());
        A.delete();
        System.out.println("outer: " + A);
    }
```

With the println that I have in this I get the following output:

```
inner:  0 0 2 3
prepend: 1 0 0 2 3
current cursor:1
outer: 1 0 2 3 //works fine the first time
inner:  1 0 1 3
inner:  0 1 1 3
prepend: 2 0 1 1 3
current cursor:1
outer: 2 1 1 3 //deletes the wrong value? Why?
inner:  2 1 1 2
inner:  2 1 1 2
inner:  0 2 1 2
prepend: 3 0 2 1 2
current cursor:1
outer: 3 2 1 2
```

Here is the relevant portions of the List class:

```
class List {

private class Node {
    //Fields

    int data;
    Node next, previous;
    //Constructor

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
        previous = null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(data);
    }
}
//Fields
private Node frontNode, backNode, cursorNode;
private int totalSize, cursorPosition;

//Constructor
List() {
    frontNode = backNode = cursorNode = null;
    totalSize = 0;
    cursorPosition = -1;
}

//length(): Returns number of elements in this list
int length() {
    return totalSize;
}

//getIndex: Returns the index of the cursor element in this list, or 
//returns -1 if the cursor element is undefined.
int getIndex() {
    return cursorPosition;
}
//prepend(int data): Inserts new element before front element in this List.
void prepend(int data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    if (this.length() == 0) {
        frontNode = backNode = node;
    } else {
        frontNode.previous = node;
        node.next = frontNode;
        frontNode = node;
    }
    totalSize++;
    if (cursorPosition != -1) {
        cursorPosition++;
    }
}

//insertBefore(int data): Inserts new element before cursor element in this
// List. Pre: length()>0, getIndex()>=0
void insertBefore(int data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    if (this.length() > 0 && this.getIndex() >= 0) {
        node.previous = cursorNode.previous;
        node.next = cursorNode;
        cursorNode.previous.next = node;
        cursorNode.previous = node;
        totalSize++;
        cursorPosition++;
    } else if (this.length() <= 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: insertBefore called on empty list");
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: insertBefore called without cursor set");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to modify the list inside the `while` loop.

```
for (j = 1; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
    i = j - 1;
    key = inputArray[j];
    while (i >= 0) {
        if (key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) >= 0) {
            break;
        }
        inputArray[i+1] = inputArray[i];
        i--;
    }
    inputArray[i+1] = key;
    A.moveTo(i+1);
    A.insertBefore(j); // insert 'key' in right place
    A.moveTo(j+1);
    A.delete(); // remove old occurrence of 'key'
}
```

I replaced `>` with `>=` to make the loop stop as soon as the key is greater than *or equal to* the current element. That way the key will be inserted after equal values rather than before.

I suggest you extend `insertBefore` to insert at the start when `cursorPosition == 0`. This is a logical extension which eliminates the special cases in the insertion sort algorithm.

Comment: Thanks.I made the modifications to insertBefore so that it will work on the edge cases. However, the algorithm as you have it results in a error on the last iteration because when A.moveTo(j) is called j is the same number as the length of List.

Comment: @IanFiddes My suggestion is to make it legal for the cursorPosition to be equal to the length.

Comment: This still doesn't work :( I cannot make it legal for cursorPosition to be equal to the length - cursorPosition is 1 based, length is 0 based. However, I did change it to append the value of j in the case where it is the length.

Comment: But this doesn't work. After the 2nd iteration, values are lost because j is not equal to the item that was removed.

Comment: @IanFiddes I edited my answer to avoid inserting at the end. Please post your implementation of `moveTo()` and `delete()` if it still doesn't work.